# Does "identifierForVendor" on `UIDevice` stay the same between iCloud backup restores?

Tags: ios, icloud, itunes, uidevice

We're trying to solve an issue where we need to detect when a "device" from the perspective from our app is actually a different one.

**I was wondering if this was persisted to iCloud and iTunes backups,** or if it is re-generated on device change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`identifierForVendor` only changed when you `Uninstall` the application. once you install application then `identifierForVendor` will be same whatever task you perform like you `update your application` or you backup it to `icloud` or restore it, until you delete it. If you delete and reinstall the application then `identifierForVendor will be different!